# MongoDB: Updating a unique index to the same value fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unique-index

I have a collection in MongoDB (`posts`) with a unique index on `urlSlug`, and am using the Node library to access it. When I go to update a post like this

```js
const data = {urlSlug: "same-as-existing-slug", foo: "some new foo", bar: "some new bar"}

await collection.updateOne({_id: req.params.documentId}, {$set: {...data}}, {upsert: true});
```

It fails with a duplicate key error on `urlSlug`. Is this expected behavior, when updating a key that's equal to the existing key? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It will throw a duplicate value error when `urlSlug`'s value is present in other documents than `req.params.documentId`.

Comment: That's what I'd expect, however it seems to be throwing an error when I simply try to update the document where id == `req.params.documentId` (where I'm updating `urlSlug` to the same value). I'll do a bit more debugging tomorrow.

Comment: It should work, i just have tried the same in my machine it is working perfectly, i am not sure but try to [reindex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.reIndex/) it or drop that index and recreate it, **Note: This operation may be expensive for collections that have a large amount of data and/or a large number of indexes**,